# java - jmap crashes with "can not get class data for heapdump in java 8

Tags: elasticsearch, heap-dump, jmap

**jmap -F -dump:file=heap.dump 13976**

following are the error logs

> Attaching to process ID 13976, please wait... Debugger attached
>   successfully. Server compiler detected. JVM version is 25.25-b02
>   Dumping heap to heap.dump ...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
```

**Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AssertionFailure: can not get class data for org/elasticsearch/common/util/concurrent/ThreadContext$$Lambda$13110x000000010073e828**

```
at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.Assert.that(Assert.java:32)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeInstance(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:803)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AbstractHeapGraphWriter$1.doObj(AbstractHeapGraphWriter.java:95)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.ObjectHeap.iterateLiveRegions(ObjectHeap.java:353)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.ObjectHeap.iterate(ObjectHeap.java:171)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AbstractHeapGraphWriter.write(AbstractHeapGraphWriter.java:51)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.write(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:433)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.run(HeapDumper.java:62)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:83)
```